# How to use two instances of image to make an image overall wider?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I am working on a print size of 72" x 24". My image that I would like to use is about 18" x 18" at 300 dpi. I am afraid just resizing the image will result in to much loss of quality to stretch to fit 72" wide. Plus it's not in an ideal ratio compared to the print piece.

The image is darker in color with grass towards the bottom. What is a good method to take two instances of the image and overlap them to create a wider image? I tried the merge photo automation, but it just keeps putting the two images on top of each other, not using the image size by side.

What other methods can I try to merge two instances of the same photo together to create a wider image?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how anyone could feasibly answer this without seeing the photo in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you might want to start by enlarging the image normally without changing the aspect ratio. 
Enlarge it so that you will loose some parts of your original photo on the top and bottom, but be careful with repositioning and enlarging to see how much from the top and/or bottom you want to cut off. You will then be left with a smaller empty area on both the left and right side. In order to fill this area you can use the following methods that have worked fine for me several times.

It really depends on the image but what I sometimes do is the following:

- position the image in the center
- duplicate it twice
- flip the duplicates horizontally
- put one duplicate on the left side next to the original one, the other one on the right
- overlap them slightly and  use the gradient tool to hide the exact border
- use the clone stamp tool to adjust it here and there

No matter how you will do it, you will always need to do a few adjustments on the details but this method can give you a good start and save you a lot of time.

[image]

The red lines show where the original photo ends, everything after that is added using the method i just described. You can easily see that with just a little bit of extra work using the clone stamp tool you could make this look very believable. I intentionally didn't do the details for you so that you can see how it looks without putting work into it.

Another slightly different method would be:

- position the image in the center
- duplicate it **once**
- strech the image that is in the back all  the way to the sides
- use the gradient tool on both ends of the image in the front to hide the exact border
- use the clone stamp tool to adjust it here and there

And this would be the result:

[image]

Note how with this method the clouds fit a bit better whereas with the first method the grass fits better. You might want to combine them to achive a good result. And I can't stress this enough: You will always need to do a few adjustments on the details, there is no out of the box method or tool.

Comment: Thanks for the info! 
When using the gradient tool to hide the hard line. What gradient is best to use, and what transparency works best when blending the gradient layer?

Comment: Simply add a layer mask on the image and use the standard black-to-white linear gradient on the mask. On masks, white shows, black hides. If the effect is too strong, you can reduce the opacity of the mask layer.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the explanation, and examples!