# make an image wider without scaling the actual image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an layer that is rectangular, and I want to make it a square without resizing the image itself or any of the other layers. How do I do this?

Comment: You can have a look at the answer there, but use this trick vertically instead of horizontally: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57654/how-to-use-two-instances-of-image-to-make-an-image-overall-wider

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming, which may not be correct, that you do not care what shows up in the area that you need to add above and below (or right and left) of the short edge.

1. Double-click on the background layer if there is one
2. Go to "Image/Canvas Size"
3. Take the long edge dimension and make the short edge dimension to be the same
4. Click on the Center block in the Anchor setting below the dimensions if not clicked
5. Click OK

This will give you a square image with strips added to the short edge. If you like, you can add a layer below the original and fill it with anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop Go to Image > Canvas Size and adjust the area that you want you make square. But in this process it will crop those layers.

---

My Best solution would be to create a New Document with a Square area and in the previous document Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + E to create a single layer. Then Duplicate or Drag & Drop it on to the New document.
Then in the New Document Go to
Edit > Content-Aware-Scale 
and Drag the Left or Right Side slowly so the layer/image won't get distorted.
Hope it helps ^_^